# Tkinter and requests: Can fetch weather using zipcode

Tags: json, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')


def searchbyzip():
        try:
            zipcode=zipentry.get()
            api_request = requests.get("http://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?format=application/json&zipCode="+zipcode+"10001&distance=5&API_KEY=2FF97EFB-2391-4403-9001-EA249EEDACDB")
            api = json.loads(api_request.content)
            city = api[0]['ReportingArea']
            quality=api[0]['AQI']
            category=api[0]['Category']['Name']

            if category == "Good":
                weather_color='"#0C0"'
            elif category == "Moderate":
                weather_color="#FFFF00"
            elif category == "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups":
                weather_color="#FFFF00"
            elif category == "Unhealthy":
                weather_color="#FF0000"
            elif category == "Very Unhealthy":
                weather_color="#990066"
            elif category == "Hazardous":
                weather_color="#660000"

            root.config(bg=weather_color)
            apilabel = Label(root, text="City: "+city+'\n'+'Quality: '+str(quality)+"\n"+'Category: '+category, font=("Helvetica",20),bg=weather_color)
            apilabel.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
        except Exception:
            api="No internet connection"
            errorlabel = Label(root,text=api)
            errorlabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

zipentry = Entry(root)
zipentry.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2,pady=5)
zipbutton = Button(root, text="Search By Zip",command=searchbyzip)
zipbutton.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

It works for the default zipcode but it throws the exception block when I enter a custom zipcode. Really can't identify the problem here. Also I am new to tkinter and kinda exploring right now.

Comment: You have a hard-coded zipcode `10001` in your link: `"...&zipCode="+zipcode+"10001&..."`. Remove it : `"...zipCode="+zipcode+"&..."`

Comment: Did what you said. Still not working man!

Comment: What is the error?  Better show the exception by changing `except Exception:` to `except Exception as ex:` and add `print(ex)` before `api="No internet connection"`.

Comment: ya it worked. Made a rookie mistake with a hex color code.

Comment: Did the line `weather_color='"#0C0"'` cause the error?  It should be `weather_color="#0C0"`.

Comment: exactly brother. Also, how do you highlight bits of codes in comments? Is there a guide for formatting and stuff? I am super new here.

Comment: You can see [comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).